# MS Access 2007 Public Function for button used on various forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I know just enough programming to get myself in serious trouble. I'm building a database where I want to run a function that does the same thing each time. The only problem is the button appears on various forms. I know I need to use a public function. I managed to get the function to work as a private sub on one form but when I moved it to a module and made it into a public function, it gave me an error. It states that I have entered an expression that has no value. I suspect the problem is the link between the first form (Various Forms) and the second form (Log-Memo Line Form).

In each form, the common link is the HL# (The Transaction ID#). HLCtrl refers to a text box control on one form (the various parent forms). [HL#] refers to a text box control in the [Log-Memo Line] Form. My other issue is that the HLCtrl control has different names in different forms. Should I rename the controls to be the same name?

This is the code

```
Public Function Memo_Line()
On Error GoTo Memo_Line_Err

    Call saver
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Log-Memo Line", acNormal, "", "[HL#]=" & "'" & HLCtrl & "'", , acNormal
    Call ClipBoard_SetData([Forms]![Log-Memo Line]![Memo])
    MsgBox ([Form_Log-Memo Line].[Memo] & "---- copied to Clipboard."), vbInformation, "Clipboard Details"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Log-Memo Line"

Memo_Line_Exit:
    Exit Function

Memo_Line_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Memo_Line_Exit

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's in this line  `DoCmd.OpenForm "Log-Memo Line", acNormal, "", "[HL#]=" & "'" & HLCtrl & "'", , acNormal`

You're opening the form and filtering it according to HL# = `HLCtrl`. Assuming `HLctrl` is a control on one of your forms (the form needs to be open and have a value in there for this to work), I would either pass it as a parameter to your function or *if you're always going to be calling this function when the form with `hlctrl` is open*, you could refer to `hlctrl`  by it's whole name : `[Forms]![yourFormThatYouWantToSelectaHLNumber]![hlctrl]`

If you called this code from the form that contained the control `HLctrl`, you wouldn't need to use the full name, and you could just say `HLCtrl` or `Me.HLctrl`. Since you're calling it from a public function located outside of the form object, you need to tell it which form to look for the HLCTRL

Like  `DoCmd.OpenForm "Log-Memo Line", acNormal, "", "[HL#]=" & "'" & [Forms]![yourFormName]![HLCtrl] & "'", , acNormal`

Also, if it's a number, you probably don't need to wrap it in single quotes.

Comment: That was what I suspected also. Now my problem is to how to recode to use a parameter. This is where my coding education fails. I assume the parameter would need to list the entire control name, i.e. [Forms]![Form1]![HLCtrl] or [Forms]![Form2]![HLCtrl] etc. The primary form (Form1, Form2, or Form3) will always be open whenever the button is pushed.

Comment: Well if it's always going to be the control from that form, then you don't need a parameter, you can just refer directly to that control. Otherwise, you would have the parameter in parentheses at the function definition like `public function memo_line (yourHL as Integer)` and you would call that function in an event on your form like `call memo_line(me.HLCtrl)` and instead of referencing the control in your function, you would reference the `yourHL` variable passed in to the function.